# How to solve separable differential equation $y'=(\cos^2x)(\cos^22y)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the separable differential equation: $y'=(\cos^2x)(\cos^2 2y)$. I am stuck on this part:

$dy \over (\cos^22y)$ = $(\cos^2x)\, dx$

I have placed **y** on the left side and **x** on the right side. I am a little rusty on integration of trigonometric functions, so any help would be appreciated. My main roadblock is this:

Do I rewrite the LHS as $(\cos^2 2y)$ raised to -1, or the inner exponent of $\cos$ raised to -2?

Comment: by separation, obviously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are more likely to remember how to do the integral on the left-hand side if you rewrite it as $\int \sec^2(2y)\,dy$. And if you don't remember, $\int \sec^2 t\,dt=\tan t+C$, because the derivative of $\tan t$ is $\sec^2 t$.

For integrating $\cos^2 x$, a simple way is to use the double-angle formula $\cos (2x)=2\cos^2 x-1$. Use this to conclude that $\cos^2 x=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x)+1)$. Now the integration should not be difficult.

**Remark:** Since you are rusty at integration, after you calculate an indefinite integral, differentiate the expression you get to check whether you are right.